# Rails app for multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a service with the same five sites and one that will unite them, but everyone has to live on a separate domain. Maybe somehow run one instance Rails app redirect users depending on the domain? Or is it better to start on a new Rails app per instance?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up one instance of the rails app, and configure your http server (Apache, Nginx or whatever) to listen to connections on all of those domains?

Answer (score 0):

Genarally, there are two ways you can do that with one rails instance.

1. redirect the comming requests to diffrent uri path ('/site1', '/site2' etc) from the http server based on the domain names. I'm not a pro on setting up this. But i'm sure this is do-able.
2. redirect the comming requests to different path from the application controller in a before filter based on the value of request.url.host variable.

   redirect_to my_site1_path if request.url.host == 'www.site1.com'

You can choose either of them, it's up to you :).